# Check if a range in Excel contains DataValidation

Tags: vba, excel

One of the answers to [Determine if cell contains data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346246/7420518)
 got me thinking about an edge case I needed to solve. If `cell` happens to be a multi-cell range what's the best way to answer? The answer below returns `False` if the range contains both a cell with and without validation.

```
Function HasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim t: t = Null

    On Error Resume Next
    t = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0

    HasValidation = Not IsNull(t)
End Function
```

The answer I arrived at allows for non-contiguous ranges. I chose `Variant` as the return type in the case that there's a mix of validated and non-validated cells. Since it's neither `True` nor `False` a `Null` seemed the best fit.

```
Public Function HasValidation(ByVal cell As Range) As Variant
    Dim tempVariable As Variant
    If cell.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim singleCell As Range
        For Each singleCell In cell
            Debug.Print singleCell.Address(True, True)
            tempVariable = Empty
            tempVariable = singleCell.Validation.Type

            If IsEmpty(tempVariable) Then
                Dim cellWithoutValidationFound As Boolean
                cellWithoutValidationFound = True
            Else
                Dim cellWithValidationFound As Boolean
                cellWithValidationFound = True
            End If

            If cellWithValidationFound And cellWithoutValidationFound Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                HasValidation = Null
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        HasValidation = cellWithValidationFound
    Else
        tempVariable = Null
        tempVariable = cell.Validation.Type
        HasValidation = IsNull(tempVariable)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: No. I was focusing on the multi-cell option that I neglected to properly update a single-cell range.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend caution re: using On Error statements in utility functions like this. Any custom error handling in the main procedure (ie "On Error GoTo lineNum") will be overwritten by this function, so you'll have to remember to manually change it back any time you use the function in a procedure with custom error handling.

My advice would be to pick a personal rule-- either "Never use On Error statements in utility functions, only in main procedures" or "Only use On Error statements in utility functions, never in main procedures"-- and stick to it.

If you do use them, make sure that you switch back to On Error GoTo 0 for *all exits* from the function. In the first portion of the "IF" block in your current code, you only switch back if the function returns null:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim singleCell As Range
For Each singleCell In cell
    '...do stuff, then

    If cellWithValidationFound And cellWithoutValidationFound Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        HasValidation = Null
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

'On Error GoTo 0 needs to be added here
HasValidation = cellWithValidationFound
```

In this case, it's possible to avoid the "On Error" statements entirely by using the SpecialCells and Intersect methods. Only caveat is that it assumes that your range's parent worksheet contains at least one blank cell:

```
Function hasValidation(rng As Range) As Variant

    'Find first empty cell in ws and add validation
    'This ensures that at least 1 cell in ws contains validation 
    Dim emptyCell As Range
    Set emptyCell = rng.Parent.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1)
    emptyCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="1"

    'Get range of all cells in ws with validation, then remove validation from empty cell
    Dim validationCells As Range
    Set validationCells = rng.Parent.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    emptyCell.Validation.Delete

    'Get intersection of validation cells and range being tested
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    Set rngUnion = Intersect(rng, validationCells)

    'Determine whether entire/partial range has validation and return value
    If rngUnion Is Nothing Then
        hasValidation = False
    ElseIf rngUnion.Count = rng.Count Then
        hasValidation = True
    Else
        hasValidation = Null
    End If

End Function
```

It'd be possible to design a slightly safer version that accounts for sheets with no blank cells, but that scenario is so unlikely that it's probably not worth the effort.

**EDIT**: Actually, it turns out that Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) is way worse than I thought. Not only is it obscenely slow for large ranges, it also only searches the *Used Range*, not the entire sheet. So you may have no option but to use error handling.

Luckily, you can use the same basic format while incorporating On Error. Since it uses Intersect instead of looping through cells, it should be faster than your version. Also, rather than returning Null in mixed cases, it uses optional parameter that alters how the function treats ranges with a mix of validation/no validation. That's just a stylistic preference, I'm not a big fan of Null. Here's my final version:

```
Function hasValidation(rng As Range, Optional entireRange As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    'Get range of all cells in sheet containing validation
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim validationCells As Range
    Set validationCells = rng.Parent.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If no cells contain validation, return False and exit
    If validationCells Is Nothing Then
        hasValidation = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Get intersection of validation cells and range being tested
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    Set rngUnion = Intersect(rng, validationCells)

    'Determine whether entire/partial range has validation and return value
    If rngUnion Is Nothing Then
        hasValidation = False
    Else
        hasValidation = IIf(rngUnion.Count = rng.Count, True, Not entireRange)
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that `HasValidation()` returns either `True` or `False`, not `maybe?...`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HasValidation(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim itHas As Boolean, eID As Long, eSRC As String, eDESC As String

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        eID = Err.Number
        eSRC = Err.Source
        eDESC = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        itHas = Not Intersect(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation), rng) Is Nothing
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Or eID <> 0 Then
        If eID = 0 Then Err.Clear Else Err.Raise eID, eSRC, eDESC
    End If
    HasValidation = itHas
End Function
```

---

Or `GetValidationRange()` that returns a `Range` or `Nothing`

---

```
Public Function GetValidationRange(ByVal rng As Range) As Range
    Dim vRng As Range, eID As Long, eSRC As String, eDESC As String

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        eID = Err.Number
        eSRC = Err.Source
        eDESC = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set vRng = Intersect(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation), rng)
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Or eID <> 0 Then
        If eID = 0 Then Err.Clear Else Err.Raise eID, eSRC, eDESC
    End If
    Set GetValidationRange = vRng
End Function
```

---

.

In your code

- The parameter name (`cell`) implies that it expects a single cell
- The `Null` return type can cause issues (not very used in normal operations)
- As a user of the function I don't really know what to do with the result

  - Should I be looking some more for cells with validation or not?

---

**Edit**

@DanielMcCracken has a valid point about changing the error chain

- I updated the answer to preserve the previous error